# Comparing object to number, string or array

Tags: php

I just want to know, according to the documentation (1:object | 2:anything => object is always greater ==> second table http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) 
Why here :

```
$a = new stdClass();
var_dump($a > 10);
```

send us a "false" ?

Thanks in advance

Edit :

What is strange (but in accordance with the documentation) :

```
$a = new stdClass();
var_dump($a > "lkjlkjljljlkjkljljl"); // true

$a = new stdClass();
var_dump($a > array()); // true

$a = new stdClass();
var_dump($a > array("kjkl", "lkj", "llj")); // true
```

Comment: Why is chalk not equal to cheese?

Comment: Try adding a property to your object and see what happens. Empty arrays and objects are slightly different behaviours to ones with values or properties

Comment: I've tried but nothing changes.
My question isn't a troll or something. I have to pass a php certification so I try to understand what happend here.

Answer (score 0):

$a becomes converted to a number, but since you haven't provided a number it will be 0. The comparison `$a > 10` or `0 > 10` is then `false`, of course

Comment: maybe the interpreter converts your stdClass somehow?

Answer (score 0):

$a holds zero (0). so its correct since no greater value than 0 is assigned. 0 > 10 is false.